# Custom Arduino Due Random Lock up

Tags: avr, atmel

I have built my own Arduino Due Circuit board. I am having issues with it randomly locking up. I have researched the libraries and have ruled out any issues with them such as the Wire library. I am wondering could an issue with the power supply cause a brown-out that would lock it up. The only way to recover is to unplug it and plug it back in. It can run for 1 hour 1 week or months before it locks up. Does anybody have any idea what could cause this issue and how I can resolve it? Could the fuse or lock bits being set wrong  cause this type of issue?

Comment: What is your BOD (brown Out Detect) fuse set to?

Comment: Welcome :-) "*I have built my own Arduino Due Circuit board*" So what did you change, compared to the original? Any component changes (type / value / not populated etc.)? Any layout changes or did you exactly copy the PCB layout too? Please edit your question to add those details. Also add details of any testing & analysis you've done so far, to avoid anyone wasting time suggesting things you've already done. Is your hypothesis of a brown-out based on any specific testing or analysis, or just a guess? Finally, please add photos of your board into the question (ctrl+G in the editor). Thanks.

Comment: Further questions: (a) To help confirm that this is a hardware problem, and not a problem with your code, have you had your custom board hang, while running **only** the most simple "blink LED" code (and if so, can you provide a copy of that code)? (b) Have you been able to change the frequency of the hangs (i.e. make them less frequent **or** more frequent) by doing anything, during your troubleshooting so far? (c) Also, based on your troubleshooting so far, have you been able to get confidence in a particular power source, for your subsequent tests? Thanks.